# Inverting the mute / unmute function this particular html5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, video

Im wondering if you all can help me Invert the mute / unmute function for this html5 video player. Basically the function is simple: While the video is playing, it is muted. When the person overs their mouse on the video the audio unmutes. When the players mouse leaves the video, it mutes again. Please keep in mind that I do want the fade effect to still function.

I've gotten this far, but I have no idea how to invert the mute / unmute function. Below is the code. For live-demo purposes, here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/X4cu9/40/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var backAudio = $('#mediaplayer');
  var muted = false;

  $('.mute').mouseover(function() {
    var video = $(this);
    if (!muted) {
      video.attr("disabled", "");
      backAudio.animate({
        volume: 0
      }, 1000, function() {
        muted = true;
      });
    } else {
      video.attr("disabled", "");
      backAudio.animate({
        volume: 1
      }, 1000, function() {
        muted = false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="mediaplayer" class="mute"
       src="http://www18.online-convert.com/download-file/b7124f78114fba6bb5137d36b5429e6e/converted-14cf4fb1.mp4"
       autoplay="autoplay" volume="0">
</video>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? As you have it now on the JsFiddle, the audio begins playing immediately.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var backAudio = $('#mediaplayer');
var muted = true;
backAudio[0].volume = 0;

 $('.mute').hover(function(){
     var video = $(this);
     if (muted) {
         video.attr("disabled", "");
         backAudio.animate({volume: 1}, 1000, function () {
             muted = false;
         });
     }
     else {
         video.attr("disabled", "");
         backAudio.animate({volume: 0}, 1000, function () {
             muted = true;
         });
     }
 }); <!-- END | mute -->
}); <!-- END | mediaplayer -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fdpxw6rm/

Comment: Bingo! Thank you Ben, you're a wizard!

Comment: @kenhimself: Based on what you have described in your question, this solution does not work. There is no need for a muted flag. The hover function required two function the *in-hover* and *out-hover*. If the mouse enters the `frame -> video -> body`, the effect will work, but if you enter the `frame -> body -> video`; then functionality breaks...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl — As much as I appreciate your comment, due to my back of knowledge of JQuery, I'm having a difficult time understanding your explanation. Would you be so kind and submit a jsfiddle that supports your suggestion? As always, much appreciated!

Comment: Well, lets just say that the state of mute can be easily tricked if the cursor moves too quickly. Since the `onHandler` of the `hover()` is being used, there is no way to know when the mouse leaves the video.

Comment: Yes—I did notice that! If the curser moved slowly out of the frame it mutes, but when the curser moves fast, it doesn't. I thought it was a glitch, but I'm glad you noticed that. How can I modify the code in a way it follows `frame -> video -> body` instead of `frame -> body -> video`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `hover()` for this. What you have described in your question makes the use of this function better than `mouseover()` and `mouseout()`.

### jQuery & the DOM

Since the video is set for `autoplay`, you must set the initial volume for the video.

You need to set the volume directly on the DOM element. The `volume` property is not an attribute, so it cannot be set like:

```
backAudio.attr('volume', 0);
```

Instead, you must unwrap the jQuery element and set the volume property:

- jQuery way:

  ```
  backAudio.get(0).volume = 0;
  ```
- Plain JavaScript

  ```
  backAudio[0].volume = 0;
  ```

### Solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var backAudio = $('#mediaplayer');
    var mutedOverlay = $('#muted-wrapper');
    
    backAudio[0].volume = 0;
    mutedOverlay.show();

    $('.mute').hover(function () {
        var video = $(this);
        video.attr("disabled", "");
        backAudio.animate({
            volume: 1
        }, 1000, function () {
            mutedOverlay.hide();
        });
    }, function () {
        var video = $(this);
        video.attr("disabled", "");
        backAudio.animate({
            volume: 0
        }, 1000, function () {
            mutedOverlay.show();
        });
    });
});

// NOTE: This is not used, but could be helpful to you in the future.
function isPlaying(videoEL) {
    if (videoEL.currentTime > 0) {
        return !(videoEL.paused || videoEL.ended);
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}

#mediaplayer, 
#muted-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#muted-wrapper {
    display: table;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 64px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

#muted-text {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="mute">
    <video id="mediaplayer" autoplay="autoplay" volume="0"
        src="http://www18.online-convert.com/download-file/b7124f78114fba6bb5137d36b5429e6e/converted-14cf4fb1.mp4"></video>
    <div id="muted-wrapper">
        <div id="muted-text">Muted</div>
    </div>
</div>
```